# RuntimeError: Could not load cudnn library. Check your cudnn installation. Maybe using the Theano flag dnn.base_path can help you

Tags: theano, theano-cuda

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjGzC.jpg)

I don't know how to solve the problem, although I searched google.

My computer OS is win10. And following installed in a virtual environment.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3CrR.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T30Hl.png)

> UserWarning: Your cuDNN version is more recent than
> Theano. If you encounter problems, try updating Theano or downgrading cuDNN to a version >= v5 and <= v7.
>   warnings.warn("Your cuDNN version is more recent than "
> ERROR (theano.gpuarray): Could not initialize pygpu, support disabled
>
> RuntimeError: Could not load cudnn library. Check your cudnn installation. Maybe using the Theano flag dnn.base_path can help you. Current value "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.1"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I solved it like this:

1. Open dnn.py.
   (My path is : F:\Anaconda3\envs\python2_7\Lib\site-packages\theano)
2. Add 'cudnn64_8.dll' in WIN32_CUDNN_NAMES. `WIN32_CUDNN_NAMES = ['cudnn64_8.dll', 'cudnn64_7.dll', 'cudnn64_6.dll', 'cudnn64_5.dll']`